# "Uninstall old version" before installing, but can't find it

Tags: 7.0-nougat, uninstallation

Spotify doesn't show up anywhere (I used to have it). When I try to install the app, it wants me to uninstall the old version. But the old version doesn't show up anywhere. Tried going through "My Apps" and through the file menu when hooked up to a PC, and I cannot find it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Spotify may be installed as a bloat-system-app so try Apps>right upper corner the three dots>show system apps. It could be that you hided the spotify app.

Additionaly you can type in the terminal `pm list packages` and use grep to filter so like that `pm list packages | grep -i spotify`. you can uninstall it by typing `pm uninstall [package name]`

Note the above assumes you're either using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) or running the commands as root. `pm uninstall` on system apps can only be performed as root (if at all) – for the other mentioned `pm` calls, connecting via ADB is sufficient.